# Minimizing a functional constrained to maximizing another

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations

Consider the following minimization problem
\begin{equation}
\min_{\phi}\int_V d^3x\ f(\phi(x),\phi'(x)) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
to be constrained by maximizing
\begin{equation}
\max_{\phi}\int_V d^3x\ g(\phi(x)). \tag{2}
\end{equation}
I wonder if I could be provided with a simple approach to the problem. If I wanted to use Lagrange multipliers, how would the original problem be? I don't know how to implement KKT conditions, since the constraint is not an equality or non-equality, but a maximization problem.

Also, I much prefer to combine the two into a single minimization problem, like the following simplified problem

\begin{equation}
\min_{\phi} \left\{\int_V d^3x\ f(\phi(x),\phi'(x)) - \int_V d^3x\ |g(\phi(x))|^2 \right\}, \tag{3}
\end{equation}

which since we know that the second term is positive definite, does the work quite as I desire. (By the way, is it a conventional Lagrange multiplier problem with $\lambda=1$?) Since I want to keep the generality of the problem, I make no assumptions on $g$ (or, the integrand). But if any are needed, please let me know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization

Comment: Wow! This seems exactly what I am looking for! Still, I don't know how it works for my problem. Any similar examples?